# Adding smallrye tracing to Wildfly 23

Tags: wildfly, microprofile, opentracing, smallrye

I'm trying to add microprofile opentracing subsystem to Wildfly23 using thins guide: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_admin-guide/subsystem-configuration/MicroProfile_OpenTracing_SmallRye.adoc

However, the second step fails:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=microprofile-opentracing-smallrye:add
    ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] {
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0369: Required capabilities are not available:
    org.wildfly.microprofile.config; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I tried adding microprofile config using this model as a reference: https://docs.wildfly.org/23/wildscribe/subsystem/microprofile-config-smallrye/index.html however i get this error

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=microprofile-config-smallrye:add
    ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] {
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [(\"subsystem\" => \"microprofile-config-smallrye\")]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

What am i missing? The doc seems fresh enough, last updated in March on 2021...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to install the extensions "org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config-smallrye" and "org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing-smallrye" before adding the subsystems.
Also wildfly provides a standalone-microprofile.xml that can server as example.

Comment: I tried adding extensions using jboss-cli as well, but for some reason it was failing just like subsystems. However, once i added required extensions and subsystems manually to my standalone.xml it worked. Perhaps they have to be added all at the same time using a batch file.

Comment: yes extensions have to be loaded (at boot only iirc) to have access to the subsystem

Answer (score 0):

With the jboss-cli one can add these "subsystems" not as the Red Hat describes it in their documentation `/subsystem=microprofile-config-smallrye:add()` but as:

```
/extension=org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config-smallrye:add
```

and then!

```
/subsystem=microprofile-config-smallrye:add()
```

so basically adding first the extension and then setting it as a subsystem:

```
/extension=<extension-qualified-name>:add
/subsystem=<extension-name>:add()
```